# RxJS (Interval) Observable wait for last observable to complete

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I want an interval observable which waits for the last execution.
This are my tries.

Simple thing which not wait.

```
interval(1000)
  .subscribe(async x => {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1000));
    console.log('Got counter', x);
  });
```

Results in: 4, 1, 2, 6, 9, 7, 6, 3, ...

Next try but a bit bad.

```
let alreadyRunning = false;
interval(1000)
  .pipe(skipWhile(() => alreadyRunning))
  .subscribe(async x => {
    alreadyRunning = true;
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1000));
    console.log('Got counter', x, alreadyRunning);
    alreadyRunning = false;
  });
```

skipWhile waits only **before** the first thing is true.

Now I tried switchMap which also not works.

```
interval(1000)
  .pipe(switchMap(() => from(new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1000)))))
  .subscribe(async x => {
    console.log('Got counter', x);
  });
```

Also not working:

```
interval(1000)
  .pipe(switchMap(x => from(async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1000));
    console.log('Got counter', x);
    return x;
  })))
  .subscribe(async x => {
    console.log('X', x);
  });
```

Is there a solution to realize that? Waiting for last observable to finish?
After the subscribe there is no chance to do that.
So how I can do this before.

//edit 1:
What I want?

I have an interval which executes an HTTP Request within.
So when the HTTP Request waits for few seconds the next interval will be executed so that the request ist executed multiple times.

That I want to avoid.

MergeMap is not working, too.

```
interval(1000)
  .pipe(mergeMap(x => from(new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(x), Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1000)))))
  .subscribe(async x => {
    console.log('Got counter', x);
  });
```

Comment: Sorry Patrick, I see you went to the effort to write our your question in detail, but it isn't clear what you're asking or what you want.  For example, there is no last emission in any of your examples, so how can you wait for it?

Comment: Am I correct, that the goal is to emit constantly increasing values from 0 to infinity, but wait a random time before the next emission?

Comment: I agree with Daniel Gimenez, I don't really understand the behaviour you're looking for. Could you please clarify?

Comment: `interval$.pipe(
   skipUntil(
      observable$.pipe(last())
   )
)`

Comment: @DanielGimenez I have a http request and want that this waits until the last is done. I updated the text. Hopefully its more clear? Like Promise.resolve().then().then().then() I need Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(async () => { WAIT FOR LAST ASYNC }).

Comment: Use the repeat operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but if user AJT82 is right (Ie, You'd like to drop any emissions from the interval while the previous request hasn't completed)

Here's how I would implement this:

```ts
interval(1000).pipe(
  tap(_ => console.log('interval hits every second!')),
  exhaustMap(_ => {
    console.log("request has started!")
    return timer(3000).pipe( // simulation that takes 3 seconds to complete
      tap(_ => console.log("request has finished!"))
    )
  })
).subscribe({
  next: v => console.log("Value emitted: ", v),
  error: e => console.log("Error emitted: ", e),
  complete: () => console.log("Complete emitted")
});
```

#### An Aside on async/await

Observables are a strict superset of promises. This means that if you can do something with a promise, you can do it with an observable as well.

Unlike Promises though, Observables don't have special syntactic sugar like async/await.

Observables interoperate with Promises fairly well. Most operators work with promises as well as with observables by converting promises for you in the background.

This makes it helpful if your project is using one and you'd like to include a library that uses the other.

**On the other hand**, if your code is already using the machinery of observables, there is **never ever** a reason to use promises. This is a code-smell should be avoided unless you really have pretty good reasons.

Comment: Nice one! I'm pretty sure OP means "previous", not "last" :)

Comment: This is very perfect :-) Thank you very much! Never heared about exhaustMap. So when request is finished. When I unsubscribe the observable the whole queue is cancelled so its pretty fine.